# jquery before() is out of order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where you can click a link that says "add a keyword" and an input will appear and you can enter the keyword, and then convert it into a span tag on blur or the "return" key. However, I've been adding onto it to allow for an "autocomplete" feature, so I'm trying to insert a

```
<ul></ul>
```

after my input in order to do a .load inside the list.

The relevant code I have is:

```
var addKeywordId = 0;
$('a.add_keyword').live('click', function(){
    $(this).before('<input type="text" class="add_keyword" id="addKeyword'+addKeywordId+'" /><ul><li>hi</li></ul>');
    $('.add_keyword').focus();
    addKeywordId++;
});
```

The problem is, that my HTML structure ends up looking like this:

```
<ul><li>hi</li></ul>
<a class="add_keyword">+ add keyword</a>
<input id="addKeyword0" class="add_keyword" type="text />
```

INSTEAD OF

```
<input id="addKeyword0" class="add_keyword" type="text />
<ul><li>hi</li></ul>
<a class="add_keyword">+ add keyword</a>
```

Anybody know why my HTML is added out of the order I specified??

Thanks

EDIT: This seems to be working fine in Google Chrome, but not in Mozilla Firefox.. :(

Comment: I don't know why it's added out of order, but if it's the case, why not just swap the two elements around to achieve what you want to achieve? `$(this).before('<ul><li>hi</li></ul><input type="text" class="add_keyword" id="addKeyword'+addKeywordId+'" />');`

Comment: Seems to work as intended here: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/dFLMC/

Comment: Hmm you're right mblase75..it does work fine there...I tried copying my entire javascript and stuff over but still couldn't replicate the problem...I have no idea where to even start debugging this...

Comment: does the same thing happen if you instead use this? $('<input type="text" class="add_keyword" id="addKeyword'+addKeywordId+'" /><ul><li>hi</li></ul>').insertBefore($(this));

Comment: Yes, I've tried both insertBefore() and before() :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to the weird rejiggering of code Firefox does to try to display things even when there are errors. I've seen it where I miss a closing div, IE freaks out (as it should) and Firefox looks fine, as it ignores that you missed adding the ending div and guesses.

You could try a 2 stage thing. I would add an id to the ul tag, then add the input before it.

```
$(this).before('<ul id="ulid"><li>hi</li></ul>');
$('#ulid').before('<input type="text" class="add_keyword" id="addKeyword'+addKeywordId+'" />');
```

Happy haxin.

_wryteowl

Comment: That two stage thing worked perfectly. I was so focused on figuring out what was wrong, I didn't think of trying an alternate path. Thanks mucho!!